# Unable to save InMemoryUploadedFile to model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:

```python
class IdentifierImage(models.Model):
    super = models.ForeignKey(Super)
    identifier = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=32, db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/identifierimages/%Y/%m/', blank=True, null=True, )

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('survey', 'identifier'),
        )
```

I also have a form (NOT a `ModelForm` and will never be) which uploads an image file, and I get it as an `InMemoryUploadedFile`. From the `Super` class I create the `IdentifierImage` object and try to save it with:

```python
def save_identifier_image(identifier, image):
    identifier_image, created = self.identifierimage_set.update_or_create(identifier=identifier)
    <logics to remove old images, disabled for current tests>
    identifier_image.image.save(image.name, image)
```

, where `identifier` is a valid string, and `image` is the `InMemoryUploadedFile`.

However saving of the `InMemoryUploadedFile` to model fails with `SuspiciousFileOperation`, and shows me: The joined path (C:/`</identifierimages/%Y/%m/>`) is located outside of the base path component (`<MEDIA_ROOT>`).

Why does this happen?

Why does it try to save under `C:/` instead of under the media root? Or is something completely different going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try without the leading slash in your ImageField's `upload_to` path:

```
>>> os.path.join("/whatever", "/else")
'/else'
```

Comment: I have a mixed feeling of "doh!" and "I love you" right now. I can't believe I haven't seen that. Will try it out first thing Monday.

Comment: It should be added to context that I have spent hours on this, and this question is the manifestation of me giving up, and trying to lay it down for the weekend. Now at least I have something new to try out Monday :-)